# Pandas - count since last transaction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (call it `txn_df`) that contains monetary transaction records, here are the significant columns in this problem:

```
txn_year    txn_month   custid  withdraw    deposit
2011        4           123     0.0         100.0
2011        5           123     0.0         0.0
2011        6           123     0.0         0.0
2011        7           123     50.1        0.0
2011        8           123     0.0         0.0
```

Assume also that we have multiple customers here. `withdraw` and `deposit` 0.0 value for both means no transaction has taken place. What I want to do is to produce a new column that indicates how many months has occurred since there was a transaction.  Something similar to this:

```
txn_year    txn_month   custid  withdraw    deposit     num_months_since_last_txn
2011        4           123     0.0         100.0       0
2011        5           123     0.0         0.0         1
2011        6           123     0.0         0.0         2           
2011        7           123     50.1        0.0         3
2011        8           123     0.0         0.0         1
```

The only solution so far that I can think of is to produce a new column `has_txn` (which is either 1/0 or True/False) when either one of `withdraw` and `deposit` has value > 0.0 but I can't continue from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one way to solve this problem,

```
df['series'] =  df[['withdraw','deposit']].ne(0).sum(axis=1)
m = df['series']>=1
```

As @Chris A commented,

```
m = df[['withdraw','deposit']].gt(0).any(axis=1) #replacement for above snippet,

df['num_months_since_last_txn'] = df.groupby(m.cumsum()).cumcount()
df.loc[df['num_months_since_last_txn']==0,'num_months_since_last_txn']=(df['num_months_since_last_txn']+1).shift(1).fillna(0)
print df
```

Output:

```
   txn_year  txn_month  custid  withdraw  deposit
0      2011          4     123       0.0    100.0
1      2011          5     123       0.0      0.0
2      2011          6     123       0.0      0.0
3      2011          7     123      50.1      0.0
4      2011          8     123       0.0      0.0
   txn_year  txn_month  custid  withdraw  deposit  num_months_since_last_txn
0      2011          4     123       0.0    100.0                        0.0
1      2011          5     123       0.0      0.0                        1.0
2      2011          6     123       0.0      0.0                        2.0
3      2011          7     123      50.1      0.0                        3.0
4      2011          8     123       0.0      0.0                        1.0
```

Explanation:

1. To get transaction happened or not use `ne` and sum to get values in binary.
2. when transaction is 1 create the series from 0,1,2...n using `groupby`, `cumsum`, `cumcount`.
3. rearrange the value for `0` using `.loc`

Note: May be I have added more complex to solving this problem. But It will give you an idea and approach to solve this problem.

Solution for considering customer Id,

```
df=df.sort_values(by=['custid','txn_month'])
mask=~df.duplicated(subset=['custid'],keep='first')
m = df[['withdraw','deposit']].gt(0).any(axis=1)
df['num_months_since_last_txn'] = df.groupby(m.cumsum()).cumcount()
df.loc[df['num_months_since_last_txn']==0,'num_months_since_last_txn']=(df['num_months_since_last_txn']+1).shift(1)
df.loc[mask,'num_months_since_last_txn']=0
```

Sample Input:

```
   txn_year  txn_month  custid  withdraw  deposit
0      2011          4     123       0.0    100.0
1      2011          5     123       0.0      0.0
2      2011          4    1245       0.0    100.0
3      2011          5    1245       0.0      0.0
4      2011          6     123       0.0      0.0
5      2011          7    1245      50.1      0.0
6      2011          7     123      50.1      0.0
7      2011          8     123       0.0      0.0
8      2011          6    1245       0.0      0.0
9      2011          8    1245       0.0      0.0
```

Sample Output:

```
   txn_year  txn_month  custid  withdraw  deposit  num_months_since_last_txn
0      2011          4     123       0.0    100.0                        0.0
1      2011          5     123       0.0      0.0                        1.0
4      2011          6     123       0.0      0.0                        2.0
6      2011          7     123      50.1      0.0                        3.0
7      2011          8     123       0.0      0.0                        1.0
2      2011          4    1245       0.0    100.0                        0.0
3      2011          5    1245       0.0      0.0                        1.0
8      2011          6    1245       0.0      0.0                        2.0
5      2011          7    1245      50.1      0.0                        3.0
9      2011          8    1245       0.0      0.0                        1.0
```

Explanation for considering Customer ID,

1. The above code works based on the interval between [1,1]. So to make the same format, sort df by cust_id and txn_month, For future you could add txn_year.
2. fillna(0), won't be work here, Because shift will not create NaN for next customer. To reset into 0 Find duplication of customer Id and take first value replace that into 0.

Comment: great answer. Suppose the case where there was both 'deposit' AND 'withdrawal' in a month. `df['series']` would be `2` and therefore not picked up by the logic of your boolean mask `m`. You could potentially condense lines 1 and 2 down with: `m = df[['withdraw','deposit']].gt(0).any(axis=1)`

Comment: @chris A - you are right. Thanks for the catch. Updated to the solution

Comment: Just curious, does this solution include the grouping by `custid`?

Comment: @menorah84 - No it won't, It's based on position starting from 1 to ending to 1. But you can apply this same after sorting your dataframe by cust id. then you have to replace fillna command with starting of custid

Comment: sorry, to be posting something so late on this post, but is there a way to do this in PySpark?